# Lightgallery with images in separate divs

Tags: jquery, web, gallery, lightgallery

I have multiple images in rows and I want [Lightgallery](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery) to capture all the images on my page. I can only seem to get separate light galleries for each row instead of one big gallery. The problem occurs because I have sets of images inside divs, with multiple divs in one big container. How can I get all the images in retreats-image-container to merge/join/combine into one gallery?

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="retreats-image-container">
    <div class="row row-center">
        <a href="img/retreats/retreats1.jpg">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center retreats-img">
                <img src="img/retreats/retreats1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" title="Special events" alt="Special events">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="img/retreats/retreats2.jpg">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center retreats-img">
                <img src="img/retreats/retreats2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" title="Beauty and makeup" alt="Beauty and makeup">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="img/retreats/retreats3.jpg">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center retreats-img">
                <img src="img/retreats/retreats3.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" title="Special events" alt="Special events">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="img/retreats/retreats4.jpg">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center retreats-img">
                <img src="img/retreats/retreats4.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" title="Special events" alt="Special events">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-center">
        <a href="img/retreats/retreats5.jpg">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center retreats-img">
                <img src="img/retreats/retreats5.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"title="Special events" alt="Special events">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="img/retreats/retreats6.jpg">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center retreats-img">
                <img src="img/retreats/retreats6.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  title="Special events" alt="Special events">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="img/retreats/retreats7.jpg">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center retreats-img">
                <img src="img/retreats/retreats7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  title="Special events" alt="Special events">
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="img/retreats/retreats8.jpg">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 text-center retreats-img">
                <img src="img/retreats/retreats8.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  title="Special events" alt="Special events">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript:

This creates 2 galleries of 4 images

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".row").lightGallery();
});
```

This doesn't work, but it's essentially what I want to do to get one gallery of 8 images

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#retreats-image_container").lightGallery();
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use selector property to select all `a` tags inside `#retreats-image_container`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#retreats-image_container").lightGallery({
        selector: 'a'
    });
});
```

You can check list of supported markups [here](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/html-markup.html).